# Safari iFrame HTTP header redirect issue

Tags: http, redirect, iframe, safari, header

The problem that I'm having is that I have created and iFrame that is going to a secure online 3rd party cart.  The iframes loads properly with all other browsers, IE, Chrome and Firefox but with Safari I get an error of "too many HTTP header redirects" in the window activity and the frame doesn't load.  If I load the site just in Safari outside of the iFrame it load just fine but not in the iFrame.  The redirects come from the 3rd part site that sets some sessions and cookies for first time visitors then lands them on their sign-in page.  If you have visited the page before and cookies and sessions are set then the page will load in the Safari iFrame just fine.

I'm trying to find, to no avail, a solution to this so that the site users do not have to pre-load the 3rd party site before using the iFrame on our site.  Is there something in the programing to disable the HTTP redirect limit in Safari and allow the page to do what it needs to do like the other browsers allow?  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4):

I found the issue, the issue was that Safari's default setting is to allow cookies from sites that it visits, since they never visited the site that is in the iFrame the cookie isn't set thus causing the loop inside of the iFrame.

Comment: How to bypass this if the visitation before hand is no option. Users are opening the iframe for the first time and thus Safari causes the redirect loop... ?

Comment: Facing the same issue. When loading a page with iframe embed for the first time, the page redirected to the iframe url.